# Проблема с функциями, for, return, возможно структурой кода

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, lxml, функции

Я пишу парсер (по нескольким урокам) html страниц. Не совсем понимаю как устроить структуру и взаимодействие между функциями (передачу данных из одной функции в другую).

Сайт состоит из 100 однотипных страниц, с листингом страниц внизу вида 1,2,3,4,5 ... 100 далее

Главная функция которая разбирает контент, на первой странице (остальные странице ей идентичны по типу контента) полностью работает и записывает данные в "словарь".
Есть задача сформировать список ссылок, приблизительно как это сделать циклом for я понял, но у меня почему то все это не работает, но я не совсем понимаю на каком моменте и как должна передоваться информация либо в другую функцию либо "кодом" ниже...

**Логическая структура:**

- грузим библиотеки
- формируем урл первой страницы
- указываем путь (тэги) на контент для парсинга
- указываем путь (тэги) на контент где содержится листинг страниц
- запускаем функцию по загрузки контента с 1 листа, сохраняем контент в местный  словарь, и выгружаем его в глобальный
  "кортеж\масив"
- запускаем функцию выгрузки кол-ва страниц - берем последнюю страницу, генерируем числа от 2 до 100 (в моем примере) - итого 99
  чисел создает цикл for, - эти значения 2,3,4,5 - 99 идут в
  аналогичную функцию которая дублирует основную функцию по сохранению 
  контента но без вызова функции по загрузки кол-ва страниц (что бы не 
  было рекурсии).
- в идеале что бы не получить "блок" от сайта или не пропустить страницы, сделать рандомную паузу между "открытием" страниц например 
  3-5 секунды (но это я потом разберусь)
- когда скачена и пропарсена, последняя страничка и данные преданны в courses[] вызывается функция по сохранению и экспорт

**Код парсера**.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from lxml.html import fromstring
import cssselect
from lxml.etree import XMLSyntaxError 

URL1 = 'www.site.ru/'
PAGE1 = '1' # номер страницы
URL2 = 'blabla'

URL = URL1 + PAGE1 + URL2 # итоговый урл - главная страница.
ITEM_PATH = '.1' # путь на парсинг необходимый даты
PAGE_PATH = '.paging' # путь на парсинг "кол-ва" страниц, я решил взять последнее число (в нашем примере это 100 - и сгенерировать 100 ссылок по которым должен пройти парсер.
courses = [] # как я понял это глобальная переменная если её так можно назвать и сюда будут добавляться по завершению функции данные, отсюда же они будут выкачиваться в  excel.
def parse_courses(): #выкачивает данные из первой страницы, основная функция с которой все ок.
    f = urlopen(URL) #открывает итоговый урл первой страницы
    list_html = f.read().decode('utf-8') #читаем, и декодируем
    list_doc = fromstring(list_html)
    for elem in list_doc.cssselect(ITEM_PATH): # парсим данные которые нужны, товары например.
        a = elem.cssselect('a')[1]
        title = a.get('title') 
        course = {'title': title} # сохраняем данные в "словарь" как я понял
        get_page_count(); # скачав первую страницу, и обработав её данные вызываем функцию которая распарсит последний № страницы.
def get_page_count(): # функция которая выкачивает дату номера страницы
    for elem in list_doc.cssselect(PAGE_PATH):
        pagenumber = elem.cssselect('li')[-1] # берем последнюю цифру, print её мне выдавал 
        pagenum = pagenumber.text
        print(pagenum) # возможно её нужно перевести в int()
        int(pagenum) # с этого момента начинается заминка!!!
        #return(page) # если честно не совсем разбираюсь в функция и как они "перекидывают данные из одной в другую"
    url = urljoin(URL1 + page + URL2) # этот url должен генерировать 99 ссылок от 2 до 100
    #дальше эти 99 урлов должны запускать или копию функции parse_courses() или передавать ссылки в нее для выкачивания аналогичных данных с 2 по 100 страницу

def main():
    parse_courses() # запускается первой

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

ps: пост (вопрос) получился размашистый, если я что то пропустил, и не точно сформулировал дайте знать, я старался дать как можно больше информации. Я отвечу, и отредактирую вопрос для более точного формулирования.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот наглядный пример функций, которые возвращают некоторое значение:

```
def get_var(var):
      return var * 2


def set_var(var):
    return get_var(var)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    var = set_var(5)
    print var
```

Если функция возвращает некоторый результат, этот результат может быть присвоен переменной. То есть, запись "var = set_var(5)", грубо говоря, аналогична установке значения переменной - "var = 5 * 2".

По умолчанию - если инструкция return в функции не указана - функция вернет None. Например:

```
def test_get_result(var):
    var *= 2

>>> print test_get_result(5)
>>> None
```

И наоборот:

```
def test_get_result(var):
    var *= 2
    return var

>>> print test_get_result(5)
>>> 10
```